# Limiting Azure data explorer update policy input

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We have a use case where we are saving telemetry and statistic data from the machines but the update policy, which is supposed to process the raw data, is giving us trouble and running out of memory.

```
Aggregation over string column exceeded the memory budget of 8GB during evaluation
```

We have two tables, the 'ingest-table' where the data is initially being ingested to and the 'main-table' where it should end up.
We are in a process of migrating from another solution to ADX and have to ingest a high volume of data.

The raw data is in a matrix format, which means that one message from a machine will end up as multiple rows/records in the ADX database. We use mv-expand for the breakdown and the query is pretty much doing that, among with some data formatting.
So, our update policy looks like the following:

```
['ingest-table']
| mv-expand Counter = Data.Counters
| mv-expand with_itemindex = r Row = Rows
| mv-expand Column = Rows[r].Data
| project ...
```

I don't see any way how could I improve the processing query itself and I'm looking for a way to somehow limit the number of the record which the update policy function would receive.

I've tried playing around with the ingestion batching (MaximumNumberOfItems = 1000) and also sharding policy (MaxRowCount = 1000) for the 'ingest-table' but it does not have any effect on the number of records the update policy is pulling it at once.
My idea is to let only 1000 items at once to be processed by the update policy function because I've manually tested and it works fine to up to 5k record but fails closly above that.

Any suggestion what we could do in this case and how I can achieve that?

EDIT:
An example raw message which has to be processed by the update policy.
The number of rows the policy has to generate is the number of COUNTERS * ROWS * COLUMNS. In this case it would mean that we end up with ~1200 rows after this single message is processed.
I do not see any other way that doing a mv-expand here.

```
{
  "Name": "StatisicName",
  "TimeInterval": {
    "StartUtc": 1654221156.285,
    "EndUtc": 1654221216.286
  },
  "Legend": {
    "RowLabels": [
      "0",
      "0.04",
      "0.08",
      "0.12",
      "0.16",
      "0.2",
      "0.24",
      "0.28",
      "0.32",
      "0.36",
      "0.4",
      "0.44",
      "0.48",
      "0.52",
      "0.56",
      "0.6",
      "0.64",
      "0.68",
      "0.72",
      "0.76",
      "0.8",
      "0.84",
      "0.88",
      "0.92",
      "0.96",
      "1",
      "1.04",
      "1.08",
      "1.12",
      "1.16",
      "1.2",
      "1.24",
      "1.28",
      "1.32",
      "1.36",
      "1.4",
      "1.44",
      "1.48",
      "1.52",
      "1.56",
      "1.6",
      "1.64",
      "1.68",
      "1.72",
      "1.76",
      "1.8",
      "1.84",
      "1.88",
      "1.92",
      "1.96"
    ],
    "ColumnLabels": [
      "Material1",
      "Material2",
      "Material3",
      "Material4",
      "Material5",
      "Material6",
      "Material7",
      "Material8",
      "Material9",
      "Material10",
      "Material11",
      "Material12"
    ]
  },
  "Counters": [
    {
      "Type": "Cumulative",
      "Matrix": {
        "Rows": [
          {
            "Data": [
              6.69771873292923,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0.01994649920463562,
              0.017650499296188355,
              0.007246749711036683,
              0.003443999862670899,
              0.1422802443265915,
              0,
              0,
              0.0008609999656677247
            ]
          }
          //,{...} ... for each row of the matrix
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Count",
      "Matrix": {
        "Rows": [
          {
            "Data": [
              0.0001434999942779541,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0.0001434999942779541,
              0.0001434999942779541,
              0.0001317590856552124,
              0.0001434999942779541,
              0.00014285165093031273,
              0,
              0,
              0.0001434999942779541
            ]
          }
          //,{...} ... for each row of the matrix
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The query seems problematic. Please share a data sample.

Comment: Added an example of the message we receive.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see in your code is this:

```
| mv-expand with_itemindex = r Row = Rows
| mv-expand Column = Rows[r].Data
```

You explode `Rows` and get the exploded values in a new column called `Row`, but then instead of working with `Row.Data`, you keep using the original unexploded `Rows`, traversing through the elements using `r`.
This leads to unnecessary duplication of `Rows` and it is probably what creates the memory pressure.

---

Check out the following code.
You can use the whole code and get the data formatted as a table with columns `Material1`, `Material2` etc., or exclude the last 2 rows and simply get the exploded values, each in a separate row.

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
let p_matrixes  = 3;
let p_columns   = 12;
let p_rows      = 50;
let ['ingest-table'] =
range i from 1 to p_matrixes step 1 
| extend StartUtc            = floor((ago(28d + rand()*7d) - datetime(1970))/1ms/1000,0.001)
| extend EndUtc              = floor((ago(rand()*7d) - datetime(1970))/1ms/1000,0.001)
| extend RowLabels           = toscalar(range x from todecimal(0) to todecimal(0.04 * (p_rows - 1)) step todecimal(0.04) | summarize make_list(tostring(x)))
| extend ColumnLabels        = toscalar(range x from 1 to p_columns step 1 | summarize make_list(strcat("Material",tostring(x))))
| extend Counters_Cumulative = toscalar(range x from 1 to p_rows step 1 | mv-apply range(1, p_columns) on (summarize Data = pack_dictionary("Data", make_list(rand()))) | summarize make_list(Data))
| extend Counters_Count      = toscalar(range x from 1 to p_rows step 1 | mv-apply range(1, p_columns) on (summarize Data = pack_dictionary("Data", make_list(rand()))) | summarize make_list(Data))
| project i, Data = pack_dictionary("Name", "StatisicName", "TimeInterval", pack_dictionary("StartUtc", StartUtc, "EndUtc",EndUtc), "Legend", pack_dictionary("RowLabels", RowLabels, "ColumnLabels", ColumnLabels), "Counters", pack_array(pack_dictionary("Type", "Cumulative", "Matrix", pack_dictionary("Rows", Counters_Cumulative)), pack_dictionary("Type", "Count", "Matrix", pack_dictionary("Rows", Counters_Count))))
;
// Solution starts here
// Explode values
['ingest-table']
| project Name = tostring(Data.Name), StartUtc = todecimal(Data.TimeInterval.StartUtc), EndUtc = todecimal(Data.TimeInterval.EndUtc), RowLabels = Data.Legend.RowLabels, ColumnLabels = Data.Legend.ColumnLabels, Counters = Data.Counters
| mv-apply Counters on (project Type = tostring(Counters.Type), Rows = Counters.Matrix.Rows)
| mv-apply RowLabels to typeof(decimal), Rows on (project RowLabels, Data = Rows.Data)
| mv-expand ColumnLabels to typeof(string), Data to typeof(real)
// Format as table
| evaluate pivot(ColumnLabels, take_any(Data))
| project-reorder Name, StartUtc, EndUtc, RowLabels, Type, * granny-asc
```

**"Explode values" sample**

| Name | StartUtc | EndUtc | ColumnLabels | RowLabels | Type | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StatisicName | 1658601891.654 | 1660953273.898 | Material4 | 0.88 | Count | 0.33479977032253788 |
| StatisicName | 1658601891.654 | 1660953273.898 | Material7 | 0.6 | Cumulative | 0.58620965468565811 |
| StatisicName | 1658801257.201 | 1660941025.56 | Material1 | 0.72 | Count | 0.23164306814350025 |
| StatisicName | 1658601891.654 | 1660953273.898 | Material4 | 1.68 | Cumulative | 0.47149864409592157 |
| StatisicName | 1658601891.654 | 1660953273.898 | Material12 | 1.08 | Cumulative | 0.777589612330022 |

**"Format as table" Sample**

| Name | StartUtc | EndUtc | RowLabels | Type | Material1 | Material2 | Material3 | Material4 | Material5 | Material6 | Material7 | Material8 | Material9 | Material10 | Material11 | Material12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StatisicName | 1658581605.446 | 1660891617.665 | 0.52 | Cumulative | 0.80568785763966921 | 0.69112398516227513 | 0.45844947991605256 | 0.87975011678339887 | 0.19607303271777138 | 0.76728212781319993 | 0.27520162657976527 | 0.48612400400362971 | 0.23810927904958085 | 0.53986865017468966 | 0.31225384042818344 | 0.99380179164514848 |
| StatisicName | 1658581605.446 | 1660891617.665 | 0.72 | Count | 0.77601864161716061 | 0.351768361021601 | 0.59345888695494731 | 0.92329751241805491 | 0.80811999338933449 | 0.49117503870065837 | 0.97871902062153937 | 0.94241064167069055 | 0.52950523227349289 | 0.39281849330041424 | 0.080759530370922858 | 0.8995622227351241 |
| StatisicName | 1658345203.482 | 1660893443.968 | 1.92 | Count | 0.78327575542772387 | 0.16795871437570925 | 0.01201541525964204 | 0.96029371013283549 | 0.60248327254185241 | 0.019315208353334352 | 0.4828009899119266 | 0.75923221663483853 | 0.29630236707606555 | 0.23977292819044668 | 0.94531978804572625 | 0.54626985282267437 |
| StatisicName | 1658345203.482 | 1660893443.968 | 1 | Count | 0.65268575186841382 | 0.61471913013853441 | 0.80536656853846211 | 0.380104887115314 | 0.84979344481966745 | 0.68790819414895632 | 0.80862491082567767 | 0.083687871352600765 | 0.16707928827946666 | 0.4071460045501768 | 0.94115460659910444 | 0.25011225557898314 |
| StatisicName | 1658581605.446 | 1660891617.665 | 1.6 | Count | 0.75532393959433786 | 0.71081551001527776 | 0.9757484452705758 | 0.55510969429009 | 0.055800808878012885 | 0.74924458240427783 | 0.78706505608871058 | 0.18745675452118818 | 0.70192553697345517 | 0.39429935579653647 | 0.4048784200404818 | 0.14888395753558561 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Comment: Appriciate your help David, the query indeed uses less memory and is much more responsive but the whole cluster starts misbehaving as soon as I update the policy.
Instead of hitting the safe limit of 8GB, now I get an error with 'Low memory condition' which affects the whole cluster and slow things down, even other update policies connected to other tables start failing.
I think that I should change my approach and process the matrix before it is ingested into ADX.

Comment: My pleasure. This might be a valid approach, however I would like to verify a few more things. Could you **(1)** share the exact final format you are interested in? **(2)** Execute the query manually (on the same dataset / data volume that caused the exception earlier) and share the clientActivityId?

Comment: The desired format is like the example you provided but wihout the // Format as table part. The single records should end up as 1200 records stored.
It's hard to run the same query since the browser is unable to handle it because of the number of records and I'm also unaware of the size of the dataset the update policy is being called on.
KustoWebV2;4890fe37-75eb-4d95-a850-4dabd77d362c is the one with 5000 messages producing almost 900k record.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/consumeoperator

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what the number of records is the update policy works with. I've tried with 50k but even that finishes without complaining about memory.
KustoWebV2;44ab3b0a-9608-4fac-a351-338520efb654